# Javascript library scope confusion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-audio

I have an application with several js libraries. In one of them, I define a variable for my html5 audio at the top. Then I have a function that gets called that loads some html and puts it in a div. That HTML contains a button that I want to click on to play the audio. Then I load audio using the globally defined 'myaudio' variable. The structure is like this:

```
var myaudio = null;

function loadPage() {

    $.ajax({url:'myurl',
       success: function(myhtml) {
           $('#mydiv').html(myhtml);

           ... and then later....


            if (!editor && audiofile.length) { 
                var soundfile = "/media/audio/"+thisuid+"/sceneaudio/"+audiofile;
                myaudio = new Audio(soundfile).load();
                $('#audioButton').css('display','block');
                $('#audioButton').click(function() { myaudio.play(); });
            }
       }
   });
}
```

Everything works except when I click on the button, I get a 'myaudio undefined' error. I assume this is because of scope issues. At the time I click and effectively call back, myaudio is not in the scope of the call. Is this a correct assumption? How can I fix this?

I tried putting the click jquery outside the function and using the jquery .on directive but got the same result.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm having trouble making the symptom you list match up with the code you've quoted, can you produce a complete, self-contained, minimal example (e.g., an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org))?

Comment: *"...when I click on the button, I get a 'myaudio undefined' error. I assume this is because of scope issues. At the time I click and effectively call back, myaudio is not in the scope of the call. Is this a correct assumption?"* No, from your quoted code, `myaudio` is a global.

Comment: Where is the Audio "class" defined?  What does the .load() function return?  It looks to me like you _think_ you are assigning a new Audio instance when you are really assigning the return value of .load() which may be undefined.

Comment: If *myaudio* is not in scope you will get a reference error, i.e. it is not defined, not that its value is `undefined`. Oh, and the default display value for a button is *inline-block*, not *block*. Perhaps just set it to "" (empty string) so it adopts its default value.

Comment: Where do you find the `.load()` method on the Audio object?  I can't find any reference to that.  Have you checked for script errors in the browser error console or debug console?  I'm wondering if your call to `.load()` is causing an error which stop JS execution so your click handler is never installed.

Comment: load() is an HTML5 audio method. Someone suggested I use it to support older browsers.

Comment: Argh.... It was the load(). I remove that and everything works fine. False alarm. Thanks for the second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not entirely sure but maybe you can try this:

```
myaudio = new Audio(soundfile)
myaudio.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
            $('#audioButton').css('display','block');
            $('#audioButton').click(function() { myaudio.play(); });
},false)
```

Comment: The defensive pattern would be to first test that `myaudio` has a `play` method before trying to call it. But of course chaining calls discourages that.